# Add data cursor (info of hovered cell in bottom right) to calplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, calmap

I have following python code (using Python 3.12.1 version):

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import calplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

travels = dict()
for key in ['2023-10-13', '2023-10-14', '2023-10-15', '2023-10-16', '2023-10-17', '2023-10-18', '2023-10-19']:
    travels[pd.Timestamp(key)] = random.randint(0, 60)

all_days = pd.date_range(start=min(travels), end=max(travels))
events = pd.Series(travels, index=all_days)
calplot.calplot(events, edgecolor='black')
plt.title('Travel time calendar')
```

Idea is that for every date I have a travel time for that date, which is represented on calendar heatmap.

What I want is to be able to hover over any date and see:

1. Which date am I hovering over;
2. Travel time represented by integer on the date that I'm hovering over.

Example:
[image]
I couldn't capture screenshot with cursor, but at the screenshot time I hovered over first colored square (October 13, with value 19). As you can see, in the bottom right there is `x= y=` instead of concrete data showing (i.e. `x=2024-10-13 y=19`).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `calplot` doesn't store enough data to support this functionality. It is just a small visualization library.  Also, it represents a year via a `QuadMesh` in matplotlib, which has very limited support for picking etc.  Basically, you'd need to extend the internals of `calplot`.